# Change Navbar items style based on which one i've clicked last

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I would like to change the bottom border of my navbar items, only for the last one i've clicked... so i've done something like that

```js
PARENT ELEMENT

     const Navbar = () => {
      return (
        <nav className='navbar'>
          <motion.a className='logo' {...slideAnimation('left')}> some text </motion.a>
          <NavButton textNavButton={"_hello"} />
          <NavButton textNavButton={"_about-me"} />
        </nav>
    }

CHILD ELEMENT

const NavButton = ({textNavButton}) => {
    const [selectedNavButton, setSelectedNavButton] = useState("")

    const handleNavButtonClick = (string) => {
        setSelectedNavButton(string)
        console.log(textNavButton)
        console.log(selectedNavButton)
    }
  return (
    <div>
        <a className={`${selectedNavButton === textNavButton ? "selectedLink" : "links"}`} 
           onClick={() => handleNavButtonClick(textNavButton)}>
            {textNavButton} 
        </a>
    </div>
 )
}
```

So, as you can see i use props to pass down the text that should be displayed on the single element. This text goes into the state of the element with the onClick function, so when it matches the text inside the , this one has a classname of "selectedNavButton" (with the colored bottom Border), if it doesnt match it has a classname of "links" (the same css but without the borderBottom colored)

CSS:

```css
.links{
    color:white;
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(73, 73, 73);
    padding: 20px 30px 20px 30px;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.selectedLink{
    color:white;
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(73, 73, 73);
    padding: 20px 30px 20px 30px;
    font-size: 13px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #d6b600;
}
```

Any help on the errors of this code? or another way to think about this? THANKS!

Comment: Why did you wrap `textNavButton` with `{}` in the comparison? Should be `selectedNavButton === textNavButton`

Comment: Thanks that was an oversight... anyway this code doesnt seem to work as i expected. The border color now doesn't return as the normal one when i click on another button, any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selectedNavButton state should be maintained in the parent component (Navbar), and it should be passed down to each NavButton as a prop along with the setSelectedNavButton function.

**Parent**

```js
const Navbar = () => {
    const [selectedNavButton, setSelectedNavButton] = useState("")
  
    return (
        <nav className='navbar'>
            <motion.a className='logo' {...slideAnimation('left')}> some text </motion.a>
            <NavButton textNavButton={"_hello"} selectedNavButton={selectedNavButton} setSelectedNavButton={setSelectedNavButton} />
            <NavButton textNavButton={"_about-me"} selectedNavButton={selectedNavButton} setSelectedNavButton={setSelectedNavButton} />
        </nav>
    )
}
```

**Child**

```js
const NavButton = ({textNavButton, selectedNavButton, setSelectedNavButton}) => {
    const handleNavButtonClick = () => {
        setSelectedNavButton(textNavButton)
    }
  
    return (
        <div>
            <a className={`${selectedNavButton === textNavButton ? "selectedLink" : "links"}`} 
               onClick={handleNavButtonClick}>
                {textNavButton} 
            </a>
        </div>
    )
}
```